# Windows Forms: How to make the Form and a Grid Change Sizes Together?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

In C#, I have a table displayed using a `DataGridView`.  The table is significantly smaller than the form in which it appears, and so the table fills only a small portion of the upper-left-hand corner of the form.

My question:  how can I (programmatically) make either: (1) the table automatically enlarge so that it fills the form, or (2) make the form automatically shrink to the size of the table?  (And, are both possible?)

```
using System ;
using System.Windows.Forms ;
using System.Data ;

public class NiftyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
    private     DataGridView        myDataGridView ;
    private     System.Data.DataTable   myDataTable ;

    public NiftyForm ( )
        {
        this.Load  +=  new EventHandler ( NiftyFormLoadEventHandler ) ;
        }

    private void NiftyFormLoadEventHandler ( System.Object sender,
                                             System.EventArgs ea )
        {
        this.Location  =  new System.Drawing.Point ( 40, 30 ) ;
        this.Size      =  new System.Drawing.Size ( 800, 600 ) ;

        myDataTable  =  new DataTable ( ) ;
        DataColumn  myDataColumn  =  new DataColumn ( ) ;
        myDataColumn.DataType           =   typeof(string) ;
        myDataColumn.ColumnName         =   "Name";
        myDataColumn.ReadOnly           =   true;
        myDataTable.Columns.Add ( myDataColumn ) ;

        myDataColumn    =  new DataColumn ( ) ;
        myDataColumn.DataType   =   typeof(int) ;
        myDataColumn.ColumnName =   "Age";
        myDataColumn.ReadOnly   =   true;
        myDataTable.Columns.Add ( myDataColumn ) ;

        string [ ]  Name  =  new string [ 5 ]
                             { "Dwight", "Abe", "Cal", "Bill", "Eisenhower" } ;
        int    [ ]  Age   =  new int    [ 5 ] { 123, 45, 6, 78, 9 } ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ )
            {
            DataRow     myDataRow  =  myDataTable.NewRow ( ) ;
            myDataRow [ "Name" ]    =   Name [ i ] ;
            myDataRow [ "Age" ] =   Age  [ i ] ;
            myDataTable.Rows.Add ( myDataRow ) ;
            }

        this.myDataGridView             =   new DataGridView ( ) ;
        this.myDataGridView.DataSource      =   myDataTable ;
        this.myDataGridView.Dock        =   DockStyle.Fill ;
        this.Controls.Add ( this.myDataGridView ) ;
        }

    [ STAThreadAttribute ( ) ]

    static void Main ( )
        {
        Application.Run ( new NiftyForm ( ) ) ;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.myDataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

This will make the **DataGrid** fill the entire **Form**

You can also use an Anchor like so.

```
this.myDataGridView.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

This means that the **DataGrid** will resize when the **Form** resizes.

Comment: AnchorStyles.Bottom is missing in your answer.

Comment: That's because I didn't anchor it to the bottom of the form, was just showing how you can Anchor to select parts of the form :)

Answer (score 1):

Play with Dock and Anchor properties of the Grid :)
Also, you might want to try AutoSize property of the form to see if it works as you'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

Set the form AutoSize=True and AutoSizeMode=GrowAndShrink and your form will size to the grid size.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to meet a problem like this that I couldn't solve with the `Anchor` property. For me, `Dock` seems much harder to use. I guess if there are no other controls on the form, `DockStyle.Fill` is OK. Most forms tend to have other controls on them so, anchoring to all four sides is much easier.